# shell_exec() not working on php script

Tags: php, cmd, shell-exec, youtube-dl

I wants to run `shell_exec('youtube-dl -j ' . $url);`, but it's not working on my PHP script and return blank array. When I try to run manually  through cmd it's working fine.

I try localhost and also in my server but both are not working ... i already try many solution and implement it but still i can't.

Here is my PHP script

```
$url = clearString($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("url")));
$data['url'] = $url; 
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $domain = strtolower(getDomainName($url)); 
    $source = $this->DefaultModel->getSource($domain);
    $data['source'] = $domain;
    $cacheVar = "mediaInfo-".md5($url);
    if(!$mediaInfo = $this->cache->get($cacheVar)) {
        $mediaInfo = shell_exec('youtube-dl -j '.$url);
        $this->cache->save($cacheVar,$mediaInfo,$source['linkCacheTime']);
    }
}
```

When I execute `$output = shell_exec("set");` it's return output i wants to run `shell_exec('youtube-dl -j '.$url);` command on my xampp server loaclhost.

Comment: Try capturing stderr as well. That may show some information about what is happening. `$mediaInfo = shell_exec('2>&1 youtube-dl -j '.$url)`

Comment: when i run shell_exec('2>&1 youtube-dl -j '.$url) it's return : 'youtube-dl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I know how to make this work but in Linux not windows.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve above issue.

1. upload youtube-dl in public_html directory.
2. provide full path like below

```html
shell_exec('/home/{path}/public_html/youtube-dl -j
    '.$url);
```